# jquery animation does not animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

i have some jquery code that will load the chatbox of my site every second (so if any new posts arrive they become visible)

my code is here

```
function loadLog(){     
    $.ajax({
        url: "/log.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div           
            if($("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") + 20 > $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20){
                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
            }               
        },
    });
}
```

everything works fine, except it is meant to autoscroll to the bottom of the chatbox so you see the newest posts, instead it just stays at the top.

I am using the most recent version of jQuery

Comment: Try use .prop("scrollHeight"), not attr

Comment: also the if condition doesn't make sense.. `if (x + 20 > x - 20)`???????

Comment: the condition means that it will only scroll if it is possible to scroll

Comment: Set up a stripped down Proof of Concept on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Otherwise, everyone here is just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such attribute `scrollHeight` (it's property). What if you try something like this instead:

```
$box.animate({scrollTop: $box[0].scrollHeight}, 'normal');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/zBdas/

Another tip: make sure you cache your DOM queries like `$box = $("#chatbox")`, don't reselect elements again and again.

Comment: thankyou this works fine my one used to work so i dunno what happened lol